# Prevent criteria filter inside conjunctive statement

Tags: grails, groovy

An example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
def authorName = "John Smith"
def books = Book.createCriteria().list() {
    eq('genre', 'fiction')
    eq('publishDate', '2007')
    if(authorName != null){
        Author author = Author.findWhere(name: authorName)
        if( author == null ) //what do I do here? 
        else { eq('authorId', author.id } 
    }
}
```

If there is no author for the given id, then the author doesn't exist (assuming it wasn't removed) and thus there are no books written by the author. The evaluation should stop there and not return any results. What can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really 100% what you are trying to do.  If you only want to execute Book query if the author exists, you could so something like this...

```
def authorName = "John Smith"
Author author = Author.findWhere(name: authorName)
def books
if(author) {
    books = Book.withCriteria {
        eq('genre', 'fiction')
        eq('publishDate', '2007')

        // I can't tell if this is the right thing because
        // I don't know what your model looks like, but I will
        // assume this part is valid because it is what you had
        // in your example.
        eq 'authorId', author.id
    }
}
```

Depending on what your model looks like, you could also just make the authorName part of the criteria so now you don't have to execute 2 queries...

```
def authorName = "John Smith"
def books = Book.withCriteria {
    eq('genre', 'fiction')
    eq('publishDate', '2007')
    // this assumes that Book has a property named 
    // "author" which points to the Author
    author {
        eq 'name', authorName
    }
}
```

Comment: That second part looks like what I wanted. Where did you find that?

Comment: I didn't really "find" it anywhere.  I have been working with Grails for 7 or 8 years and am familiar with the criteria API.  The official User Guide covers the possibilities pretty well.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria.